# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Такое предложение из статьи: "Остается согласиться с Вангой — лишь жизнеспособный цветок, с развитой корневой системой, растущий в грунте может символизировать жизнь и процветание". Так вот, после слова "Ванга" должно быть тире или двоеточие?

Answer (score 2):

***Остается согласиться с Вангой: лишь жизнеспособный цветок, с развитой корневой системой, растущий в грунте, может символизировать жизнь и процветание.***

Двоеточие разделяет две части БСП, вторая часть дополняет первую (согласиться *в чём?*).

Растущий в грунте - обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, стоящим после определяемого слова.Ставим две запятые.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример - это бессоюзное предложение, которое можно трансформировать в сложноподчиненное, поставив на стыке частей союз "что", следовательно, ставить надо двоеточие, тире же ни в коем случае не подходит.